# "&" instead of Function[ ... ]

Tags: functions, syntax

WRI provides the code below as a "neat example" of [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fold.html). The code produces all of the subsets of `{a, b, c}`.  As an exercise, I've been trying to replace the `Function[ ..]` with the ampersand form, but no luck yet.  Thanks.

The original example:

```
Fold[Function[{s, e}, Join[s, Append[#, e] & /@ s]], {{}}, {a, b, c}]
```

Comment: In this case, you have to make a choice on which should be in "ampersand form", since the `Append[]` is dependent on both the inner and outer `Function[]` constructs.

Comment: `Fold[Join[#, Function[x, Append[x, #2]] /@ #] &, {{}}, {a, b, c}]`?

Comment: ...and kglr's comment gives the other "choice" I was talking about.

Comment: ... or `Fold[Join[#, (x \[Function] Append[x, #2]) /@ #] &, {{}}, {a, b, c}]`

Comment: Rabbit, I notice that you removed the Accept from my answer.  May I know why?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard    I am a yutz; I did not mean to retract the accept. I have restored it.  I apologize (and this is my 2nd note to you, I don't know what became of the 1st).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can use the operator form of [`Append`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Append.html), assuming version 10 or later:

```
Fold[Join[#, Append[#2] /@ #] &, {{}}, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{}, {a}, {b}, {a, b}, {c}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
Fold[Join[#, Replace[#, x_List :> Join[x, {#2}], 1]] &, {{}}, {a, b, c}]
```

> {{}, {a}, {b}, {a, b}, {c}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}

Or

```
Fold[Join[#, Function[x, Append[x, #2]] /@ #] &, {{}}, {a, b, c}]
```

> {{}, {a}, {b}, {a, b}, {c}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}

Or

```
Fold[Join[#, (x \[Function] Append[x, #2]) /@ #] &, {{}}, {a, b, c}]
```

> {{}, {a}, {b}, {a, b}, {c}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}